# Android <EditText>

Tags: android-layout

When i am adding

The following error is appearing in the graphical layout

"" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
Exception raised during rendering: java.lang.System.arraycopy([CI[CII)V
You must supply a layout_width attribute.
You must supply a layout_height attribute.
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

What should i all need to change in the xml file?

Comment: please try to add layout_height & width attribute to Layout check your parent layout attribute.. these attribute are must

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it is by incompatible version of Android 4.4W(wear)

So open you SDK Manager and delete Android4.4W related updates once it is complete then restart your eclipse.